# Easiest way to convert "new" form to "edit" form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a somewhat lengthy form using bootstrap to create a new "Patch". This would be the basic `create` form. What would be the easiest way to make this form an `edit` form?

I'm on board with the text boxes using something similar to this

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = $id;"); // replace $id with the ID variable
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo "<input type='text' name='title' value='$title' />\n";
?>
```

The part I am struggling with is which checkboxes would be auto checked. Is there a fundamentally easy way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Ah, yes. I just quickly copied this code. I'm using mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to checking box's I always set a default first (as nothing) and then add it if it exists.

```
$checked_code = ' checked="checked"';

$checkbox_name = '';
if($row['checkbox_name'] == 1){
    $checkbox_name = $checked_code;
}

echo '<option name="" ' . $checkbox_name . '>Option</option>';
```

**EDIT: Making the form useful for adding and editing**

Your URL would look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/addedit.php
```

If you visit it like that it would go to the add page, but if you added a GET on the end, it would go to the edit page for that id:

```
http://www.example.com/addedit.php?id=345
```

Then you can factor this into your code:

```
$checked_code = ' checked="checked"';
$checkbox_name = '';

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    // Editing
    $form_action = "edit.php";
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = {".$id."}"); // replace $id with the ID variable
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $title = $row['title'];

    if($row['checkbox_name'] == 1){
        $checkbox_name = $checked_code;
    }
}else{
    $form_action = "add.php";
}

echo '<option name="" ' . $checkbox_name . '>Option</option>';
```

Comment: I would put the entire edit form inside the `while($row = $patch->fetch_object()){` loop right?

Comment: Follow up, can I combine the new form and edit form based on an `if exists` sort of statement on `insert_id`? I'm not sure how that would be written. It just doesn't seem like I have to have this code written twice

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you adding and editing. I don't know what the $patch class is but you can do $row = $patch->fetch_object() and then call the data like $row['column_name']